# Function pow() int C++

Tags: c++, c, types

I have a problem when I try to multiply integer 3 pow(67, 1). It return 200 instead 201. Here is my code in C:

```
int x = 3;
x = x * pow(67, 1);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

-> 200

Can anyone explain for me. Thanks!

Comment: It 201 when I compiled locally.

Comment: 201 here as well (VS2013). What compiler / system?

Comment: I get 201 compiling with gcc 4.7

Comment: Just a guess. By any chance you are using Turbo C++?

Comment: The only explanation that I can think of is that `67`, when passed to `pow`, looses some accuracy in floating point representation and ends up being a tad smaller than `67`.

Comment: @RSahu That's what I was thinking as well... but it would have to be some weird compiler to do that.

Comment: @RSahu But it doesn't. A speculation that pow() returns 66.9999999 would make more sense, but that's hard to credit as well.

Comment: @OP Why are you computing 67 to the power of 1?

Comment: @YuHao I compiled with Turbo C++. Not a problem.

Comment: "can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" - given the problem is in floating point approximations and won't be consistently reproducible across platforms, a few people trying it and concluding it's not reproducible doesn't warrant closing the question.

Comment: @TonyD, it is true however, that there is not enough detail. What compiler, what platform? The only way to solve this is to hope it wasn't a typographical error and try ever compiler/platform under the sun.

Comment: @PaulDraper: not true... it's not a question of reproducing or "solving it", it's a question of having the experience and insights to explain why this class of issue exists and - optionally - what the usual approaches are to dealing with it (e.g. epsilon values, [nextafter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nextafter.html), rounding before use etc.).  Using your logic, we wouldn't be able to have questions where the answer was "X is Undefined Behaviour" unless we could reproduce the same U.B....! ;-)

Comment: @TonyD, you make some good points about *other* problems than can be solved with logic and experience, but I would argue that this question is not one of them. In any case, it may not be a "simple typographical error", but it certainly lacks the information appropriate to solve this problem, which is a different close reason, but still a close reason.

Comment: @PaulDraper: so, are you saying Floris' and Alf's answers are not useful or relevant to this question?  From my perspective, the question was enough for them to give a credible answer.  I don't understand your position....

Comment: @TonyD, their answers *might* be useful, though no one is able to tell (not even them). My position is that the question is of poor quality (and should be closed) because the OP did not provide sufficient information.

Comment: One more question for OP... did you `#include <math.h>`? Did your compiler generate any warnings?

Answer (score 3):

`pow(67,1)` **should not compile as C++03**, but as Tony observes in a comment, <sup>1</sup>C++11's §26.8/11 makes it valid again in C++11. Visual C++ 12.0 rejects the code as C++, evidently playing by C++03 rules. However, the g++ compiler version 4.8.2 accepts the code. With Visual C++ one gets a diagnostic about ambiguous call, since there are many overloads.

In C or in C++11 the arguments are converted to `double` and `pow` performs the exponentiation. Although these numbers can be represented exactly as `double`, the exponentiation operation is not guaranteed to produce an exact integer. E.g. it might be performed as a<sup>n</sup> = e<sup>n*ln(a)</sup>.

The result can therefore be slightly more or less than exact 67.

The multiplication expression converts integer 3 to `double`, exactly, and the multiplication is performed as `double`. If the `pow` result is less than 67 then you get a result like `200.9999999...`, if it's exact than you get `201.0`, and if it's slightly more then you get something like `201.0000001...`.

Finally the assignment back to `x` converts that back *down* to nearest `int` value, which in the first case is 200, and in the second and third case is 201.

<sup>2</sup><del>I can only conclude that the claimed result 200 must (most probably) be incorrect; that it's *incorrectly reported*.</del>

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup>C++11 §26.8/11: “Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure: 1. If any argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `long double`, then all arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `long double`. 2. Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `double`. 3. Otherwise, all arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `float`.”.</sup>
<sup><sup>2)</sup>See commentary for the deleted text.</sup>

Comment: Not true: 198 is impossible. The multiplication is also floating point so the result will be similar to 200.9999 or 201.0001 before truncation.

Comment: @david.pfx: you're right. thanks. there is no "conversion to int" that i referred to. probably came from me being tired. correcting...

Comment: i think that's it. if there's still any error feel free to fix. :)

Comment: No worries. I've done worse.

Comment: "pow(67,1) should not compile as C++" - under 26.8/11 "additional overloads sufficient to ensure" .2 "if any arithmetic argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` or an
integer type, then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to
`double` parameters are effectively cast to `double`.".  I believe this applies and GCC is correct.

Comment: @TonyD: Thanks! again I didn't see. It's not there in C++03 though. So the Visual C++ behavior rejecting the code as C++ *was* correct for C++03, unless I'm overlooking even more. Correcting again...

Answer (score 3):

Tentative explanation: the `pow` function, being performed in double precision, does not "understand" that a power of 1 means "return the exact number" and returns 66.9999. (Lots of 9's but not exactly 67). The multiplication by 3 gives something like 200.99997. Finally since the result is assigned to an `int`, this is rounded down (truncated) to 200.

Comment: When I try to print("%f", pow(67, 1)) I got 67.00000003, not 66.99999. Can you show me why?

Comment: @ILoveCoding: is that on the same PC, compiler, optimisation settings?  Did you also print out your `x` from the question, to see if it was now reporting 200 or 201?

Comment: Try to `printf("%e\n",pow(67,1)-67);` - a double precision number has lots of significant figures!

Comment: Thanks you. I think it like Cheers and hth. - Alf said below. It may be return 66.99999 or 67.000003